# ProtocolException Received when Calling WCF service 

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, exception, protocols

I am having this problem since a week now and am unable to resolve this. I have looked at various posts but found nothing related to the problem.

I have a website and a WCF service inside the same website project. It was all working fine, but suddenly, the WCF service client is not able to receive a valid response from the service.

Error message:

> ProtocolException occured
>
> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response
>   were: '
>
> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: input
>         
>         
>                body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:norma....

I don't understand what is this parameter `input`. How can I resolve this issue? The WCF service is accessible via browser using the endpoint mentioned in the `web.config`

Here is the code:

Code behind:

```
using (var client = new Agent4HomeWebsite.PhotosWebServiceRef.PhotosWebServiceClient())
{
    var temp = client.GetImageObjects();
}
```

`Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  ....
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotosWebService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint 
          address="http://localhost:49274/PhotosWebService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotosWebService"
          contract="PhotosWebServiceRef.IPhotosWebService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotosWebService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So, if you're having a problem with the response from the service, surely it would be a good idea if you knew the response from the service? Have you watched with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)? Have you turned on [WCF message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859)? You'll find that the service is sending you an error message in HTML, and you'll want to read that message and do something about it.

Comment: Okay, I will try out fiddler and WCF message logging. Thanks for your response.